# Counting the total number of components in a graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with

$30$ vertices  of  degree $1$,
$6$ vertices  of  degree $2$,
$5$ vertices  of  degree $3$,
$2$ vertices  of  degree $4$ and
$1$ vertex  of  degree $5$.

Additionally, assume $G$ doesn't contain any cycles, and has no vertices of any other degree. How many connected components does $G$ have?

I know there are $44$ vertices and $n-1$ edges in a tree, which would be $43$ edges. So would the amount of connected components in $G$ be $1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count vertices: $30+6+5+2+1=44$. Count edges: $(30+12+15+8+5)/2=35$. As you correctly state, every component must be a tree with $v_k$ vertices and $v_k-1$ edges. Since the number of edges is 9 smaller than the number of vertices, there must be 9 components.